# I want to create a box whose height should increase with time, on top of 1 video in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Sample Video:- https://automated-videos.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v8J5QCcs.mp4

In this video the white box coming from bottom with time. I want this, currently I have done using drawbox in for loop, and having enable condition.

I have achieved this using multiple drawbox with enable condition, but I am pretty sure that there will be some good way. Can you please suggest me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of filters to achieve this:

```
ffmpeg -i video -f lavfi -i color=white -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=flags=point[bar][vid];[vid][bar]overlay=x=0:y='H-min(SP*(t-ST),BH)'" out
```

A white canvas is created using the color filter. It is resized to video size. Then using overlay filter, the height is manipulated based on time so that it rises from the bottom till a maximum height and stays there. `SP` is speed of rise in pixels/seconds. `ST` is starting timestamp, in seconds. `BH` is maximum height from bottom, in pixels. You can also use frame variables like `H, h` for `SP` and `BH`.